# Why VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount returns 0 top-level controls?

Tags: c#, wpf

I modified the code present in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type) to return the first found control of a certain type. But when I try to start traversing from the window itself,  `VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount` returns `0`, although there is a grid placed on it. The modifications which I made have no effect on the result.

Here's how I call the method:

```
DockPanel panel = UIHelper.FindFirstChild<DockPanel>(this);
```

And here is my XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="216" Width="267">
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel Height="200" Width="250">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="LightBlue">
                <Button Content="01" Margin="1 1 15 1"/>
                <Button Content="02" Margin="1"/>
                <Button Content="03" Margin="1"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="25" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Background="LightBlue">
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">Processing...</TextBlock>
                <ProgressBar Value="75" Width="100" Margin="4"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <Grid>
                <TextBlock>Content area</TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>    
</Window>
```

Comment: When do you call it? Is `Window` loaded at this point? When I try it it return 3, as I would expect

Comment: It is call after `InitializeComponent()`

Comment: Call it in `Window.Loaded` event. Should help

Comment: It worked, thank you. You should post it as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you call it in the constructor visual tree is not ready yet. You should call it in `Window.Loaded` event instead

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DockPanel panel = UIHelper.FindFirstChild<DockPanel>(this);
    Console.WriteLine(VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(panel)); //returns 3
}
```

Comment: I stumbled upon another problem. It returns 1 for me, and the type of the control is `System.Windows.Controls.Border`, not a `Grid`...

Comment: what do you mean type is `Border`? You don't have `Border` but it is part of default layout of `Window` for example but you search for `DockPanel`

Comment: In the `FindFirstChild` method after `var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);` is executed, `child` is of such type. I'm not saying that the method returns such a control. The `DockPanel` is never found.

Comment: like I said `Border` is part of default layout for `Window` but `FindFirstChild` should go down the visual tree find and return first `DockPanel`. At least version from the question you quoted does that. You can download [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) and see how the visual tree looks like

Comment: There must be something wrong with my WPF window then, because the method from mentioned link returns a `Border` as well.

Comment: `Border` is the first child of `Window` and the version of `FindChild` you quoted does `T childType = child as T;  if (childType == null) ...` which will be null for `Border` and it call itself recursively looking for children. Maybe you did some changes to original `FindChild` method. Also `FindFirstChild` cannot return `Border` because you assign it to `DockPanel` varaible

Comment: The problem probably lies in the number of children. You stated that the `VisualTreeHelper` finds 3 objects, but when I run the program there is only one object found. The original method has the same effect. I'll create a new project and copy-paste all code there.

Comment: It depends on number of children of what. `Border`, which if first child of `Window`, will have one (or none) as it cannot host more and `DockPanel`, which you search for and assign to `panel` variable, will has 3 children (2 `StackPanel` and `Grid`) and if you will call `VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(panel)` it will return 3

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback, it's all well now. I *did* make a mistake in my code, plus I thought that `Grid` will be a top-level control of the window, but it turns out that the tree looks different than I imagined.